# Display Annotation Not Working In Create View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

For some reason it works in the index view for table headers but not for the create view.

Here's the relevant part of my model in the controller:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
```

I also have lazy loading:

```
public virtual Status status { get; set; }
```

I even added it to the Status model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
```

Here it is in the view:

```
       <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusId, "StatusId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("StatusId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

Yet it doesn't show up in the actual create page as "Status":

[image]

Same thing happens with another one in the same model. What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the below overload where you are explicitly providing the text to be displayed.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string labelText,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

The second parameter in the overload you are using is the `labelText` which will be displayed in the label.

Use this overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code will be

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: Oh wow I did not see that overload, I wonder why it generated that.